# I am having an issue with an extremly high non-paged memory pool

Tags: windows-10, memory, acpi, memory-leaks

I have 32gb of RAM. I noticed I was always maxed out at 30 or so GB of usage when I would only have things like Chrome open.

I used to be able to run servers. If I restart my computer memory use will go down to 250 MB but after a few days go back up to 24GB. I found the file that was causing the memory leak using poolmon and the command "findstr /s Irp *.*" with Irp being the tag that was the issue. The problem is the file that is causing the memory leak is acpi.sys and I don't know how to update it or if there is something else that I could do.

Any help would be appreciated. I am running Windows 10 Educational on a custom desktop.

Comment: How many tabs have you got open in Chrome?

Comment: can you link the output of poolmon?

Comment: i only have 10 or so tabs open in chrome, how do i send the poolmon output?

Comment: I thought you already had the output you could make share.  Well how about this, Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) can also be used to capture some data.  If you run from an admin cmd prompt: `wpr -start GeneralProfile -start Pool`  Leave that running while you believe pool memory is being leaked.1 minute tops I would say, then run: `wpr -stop C:\pool.etl "pool leak"` Can you link this output?  WPA can be used to analuze the trace. Details - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2012/11/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-7-windows-performance-toolkit/

Comment: i had issues with my network drivers and had to reset my windows, this has also fixed my memory leak issues